# How to consistently add alternating backgrounds to item views in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Up until now I used the Adapter's `onBindViewHolder` to set an alternating background based on the item's Adapter-Position.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.itemView.setBackgroundResource(position % 2 == 0 ?
            R.color.list_item_background_alternating : R.color.list_item_background);
    ...
}
```

However, this is getting more an more complicated when doing more than just showing a list. 
For example: When I remove an item and call `notifyItemRemoved(index);` the `RecyclerView` does a nice animation and the item view is gone. However, the view which replaces the removed one doesn't get bound again (for obvious & good reasons) and therefore keeps it's old background. This leads to inconsistencies with the layout and looks ugly. When I call `notifyDataSetChanged();` the backgrounds are all correct, but I lose the animation.

I have a similar problem when I'm using `SortedList` (with a `SortedListAdapterCallback`). Since the sorting seems to take place after the views are bound the backgrounds are in shambles.

What would be a proper/consistent way to implement such behaviour?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Alright, while I was writing up my question I wanted to try one thing out which I thought wouldn't work - however, it did.

I created an `ItemDecoration` and used it's `getItemOffset();` to set the view's background:

```
public class BackgroundItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

    private final int mOddBackground;
    private final int mEvenBackground;

    public BackgroundItemDecoration(@DrawableRes int oddBackground, @DrawableRes int evenBackground) {
        mOddBackground = oddBackground;
        mEvenBackground = evenBackground;
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state);
        int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view);
        view.setBackgroundResource(position % 2 == 0 ? mEvenBackground : mOddBackground);
    }
}
```

I feel a bit guilty though, that I'm piggy-bagging on `getItemOffsets()`.

Does anyone have a cleaner/better solution?

Comment: What do you mean? I did not post again. I just answered my own question.  Isn't that even encouraged? When writing up a question you have the option to provide an answer with it. Please clarify why that's bad.

Comment: no need to feel guilty, this is a good solution. As an added bonus, you can instantiate this with color resources and this code still works (for example: `BackgroundItemDecoration(R.color.colorPrimary, R.color.colorAccent)`)

Comment: That's why I annotated it as DrawableRes 

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution
The itemView refers to the View from the Layout inflater in the onCreateViewHolder.

```
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position){
    //alternate row color
            if(position % 2==0)
                holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
            else
                holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
)
```

That is all you need. Hope this helps.

Comment: That's what I mentioned in my question. That doesn't help to separate View-Binding from View-Decoration.

Answer (score -1):

note:- this code will work on Lollipop and above tested. and also fill the your constructor get context is not null if it is null then it is not work.

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        LocationModel locationModel = locationModelArrayList.get(position);

        if(position%2==0)
        {

            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.colorPrimary));
        }else
        {
           holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.colorPrimaryDark));

        }

    }
```

Comment: Same thing as the other answer and actually the same logic I provided in my initial question.

Comment: if you want to get your animation also put it inside onBindviewHolder data set observer tree to use your view is best option to mointor your recyclerview. or second one option is your animation start and stop on activity not here. when ever your item to be notify to change that particluar row only not whole adpter